# open graph tags doesn't work for me?

Tags: html, facebook, tags, facebook-opengraph, meta

I need to share the posts of my blog but I don't know why even doing the open data mark like facebook says, when I try to share facebook just show the main meta data and not the open graph data... as the posts are dynamic my tags are something like this

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="0000000000"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $title;?>"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $url;?>"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $image;?>"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $desc;?>"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="mypage"/>
```

those tags are located in the document's head of course,

btw if I use the facebook's debugger I got this

Inferred Property
The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Inferred Property
The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Inferred Property
The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Inferred Property
The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property

The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Share App ID Missing

The 'fb:app_id' property should be explicitly provided, Specify the app ID so that stories shared to Facebook will be properly attributed to the app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in url when open the share dialog

Comment: Which URL is it so we can see?

Comment: in this case would be http://subeuna.com/blog/post-8/snapchat-podria-estar-copiando-a-artistas-para-sus-filtros/

Comment: Go fix the HTML error shown here: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://subeuna.com/blog/post-8/snapchat-podria-estar-copiando-a-artistas-para-sus-filtros/

Comment: @CBroe you figure it  out! thank u so much dude